# How can I include XML into a main xml several times filled with different data?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a list of customer data which should be show as a list. This list contains buttons for contact infos.

I want to create an xml file which contains an "element" (including buttons, TextViews, ect.) and set the costumer data programatically and then add it to the main xml.

How can I do this in case of more customer data?
I was trying to use Viewstub. I have added two "element" but I was not able to set the data to de layout because ID-s were duplicated.

So the main problem is that I want to create the "element" in XML and not programatically and want to add it several times to a main xml filled with different data.

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not `ListView`?

Inflate view in Activity, fill with data and add to the layout as many times as you want.

For example:

```
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        TableRow                   row  = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, table, false);
        TextView                   name = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name));

        name.setText(data.get(i));

        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Comment: Dude i think it will throw exception (Some thing like the specified child has already  parent).